# Overlapping transparent UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, compositing

I’m overlaying two UIViews with a white `backgroundColor` at 25% opacity. In a small part, they overlap each other, meaning that at that area, they are summed to 50% opacity.

I’d like to keep that 25% opacity, even if the two views overlap, effectively meaning that in those overlapped points, each view’s opacity drops to 12.5% to total 25%.

I’ve done a little looking into compositing but I’m not sure which of these modes would help, or how I’d go about applying them to a specific part of these two `UIView` instances.

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html is what I was reading, and I found the `CGBlendMode` for drawing, if it comes to using that (though I’d prefer not to if possible!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control the compositing mode of views (or, really, `CALayer`s) on iOS.

The best solution I can think of here is to leave both views with a `clearColor` (or `nil`) background, and use a single `CAShapeLayer` to draw the background of both.  If your two views have the same parent, it's not too hard.

Let's say the parent is of type `ParentView`.  Override `layoutSubviews` in `ParentView` to create and update the backdrop layer as necessary.  Be sure to send `setNeedsLayout` to the parent view if you move either of the child views.

#### `ParentView.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ParentView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *childView0;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *childView1;

@end
```

#### `ParentView.m`

```
#import "ParentView.h"

@implementation ParentView {
    CAShapeLayer *backdrop;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self layoutBackdrop];
}

- (void)layoutBackdrop {
    [self createBackdropIfNeeded];
    [self arrangeBackdropBehindChildren];
    [self setBackdropPath];
}

- (void)createBackdropIfNeeded {
    if (backdrop == nil) {
        backdrop = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        backdrop.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.25].CGColor;
        backdrop.fillRule = kCAFillRuleNonZero;
        backdrop.strokeColor = nil;
    }
}

- (void)arrangeBackdropBehindChildren {
    [self.layer insertSublayer:backdrop atIndex:0];
}

- (void)setBackdropPath {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.childView0.frame];
    [path appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.childView1.frame]];
    backdrop.path = path.CGPath;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add them both to the same parent `UIView`, tell that `UIView` to rasterize, then set the alpha on the parent, you'll get the desired effect. I'm not sure if that fits with your display structure or performance needs.

```
UIView *parent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[parent setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[parent.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
[parent.layer setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
[parent setAlpha:0.25];
UIView *subview1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 125, 125)];
[subview1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[parent addSubview:subview1];
UIView *subview2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 75, 125, 125)];
[subview2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[parent addSubview:subview2];
```

Comment: You're assuming he wants the entire contents of the view at alpha 0.25, but that's not the same as just having the `backgroundColor` at alpha 0.25.

Comment: Actually, I had meant that he could add just the backgrounds, then move the contents (in a different hierarchy) in sync with the backgrounds.